# Netflix Eureka do not change Renews threshold

Tags: netflix-eureka, threshold

I have two Eureka server with bellow config:

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka = true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = false
eureka.server.response-cache-update-interval-ms=500
eureka.server.eviction-interval-timer-in-ms=1000
eureka.server.renewal-threshold-update-interval-ms=300000
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```

In my enviroment, It have a Oauth2 and a Zuul server, all of them have default config. And I have 3 instance of my Application with bellow config:

```
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=2
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=1
eureka.client.registry-fetch-interval-seconds=2
```

In normal case, if 3 instances of my Application are UP, the "Renews threshold" is 146 and "Renews (last min)" is 183.

But when I kill first instance of my Application and wait for long time
The "Renews threshold" still is 146, then when I kill the 2nd instance and wait for 1h. The "Renews threshold" still is 146. But the "Renews (last min)" now is 66.

Now i have the message "EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.
" because the self preservation mode is actived.

But I cannot understand why the "Renews threshold" do not update (decrease base on instances are available). It alway keep an value.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, sets renewal threshold to 60% of renewals

```
eureka:
  renewalPercentThreshold: 0.60
  server:
    renewalPercentThreshold: 0.60
```